# TypeScript type not working with spread operator

Tags: typescript, ngrx

I have a redux style reducer (I'm using ngrx) that is returning a specific type. When I use the spread operator in my return object, the typescript linter is not catching invalid properties.

Here is my interface:

```
interface MyState {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    age: number;
}
```

Here is my reducer. `Action` is an ngrx action:

```
function reducer(state = initialState, action: Action): MyState {
    switch (action.type) {
        case Actions.COOL_ACTION:
            return {
                ...state,
                propertyDoesNotExist: action.payload, // <- no error
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

I would expect that `propertyDoesNotExist` would be flagged, but it is not. I've tried casting `<CalendarState>` the return object, the state property `...(<CalendarState>state)` and using the `as` alias, but it doesn't help.

It's like the spread operator messes up the types.

Comment: You're describing classes you haven't defined in your example: Action, Actions, CalendarState. Could you complete your example? Best is to also provide it in [code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/).

Comment: Well, That's like someone asking a .NET question and then a commenter saying "We don't know what .NET classes you're using, could you add those?" Not really, I can't really add the ngrx library's code. This is why I prefaced with saying a ...redux style reducer... I could restructure my question to display this issue, but I'd have to come up with that example. This is basically the code I'm working with now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By using `...state`, the returned expression is no longer an object literal, and TypeScript won't complain if it's a subtype of the return type (i.e. has extra properties). I ran into this problem myself and wrote a little helper function to signal extra properties:

```
const applyChanges = <S, K extends keyof S>(state : S, changes : Pick<S, K>) : S =>
  Object.assign({}, state, changes);
```

(using `Object.assign` instead of spread operators because of this issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14409)

To use `applyChanges`, simply replace

```
return {...state,
    propertyDoesNotExist: action.payload, // <- no error
};
```

with

```
return applyChanges(state, {
    propertyDoesNotExist: action.payload, // <- error
});
```