# How to implement ES6 Spread Syntax on angular 6

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, syntax, spread

I am using Angular CLI with angular 6 version. I am facing issue implementing the spread syntax.

here is the code example,

```
...
baseFunction(): void {
const params = [a, b, c];
const output = this.spreadFunction(...params);
console.log(output);
}

spreadFunction(attribute1, attribute2, attribute3 ): string {

...
return 'anything';

}
```

Error message: expected 3 arguments but got 0 or more.

Note:
 Nothing been helpful updating the 
 `"target": "es5"`, to `"target": "es6"` on tsconfig.json

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

lol, same here check this:

[TypeScript type not working with spread operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44525777/typescript-type-not-working-with-spread-operator)

also, I did found a way to do this without the spread operator, there is a way to use Object.assign

as found in the link above, i found another way, just use JSON.stringify and then JSON.parse again, this will create a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

Then you actually don't need to get three parameters in the `spreadFunction`, you can use just one parameter there:-

```
spreadFunction(...params): string {
  // code here
  // it will output the array passed at the time of calling the function
  console.log(params)
  // return 'anything';
}
```

See the [use of spread operator](https://medium.com/@luke_smaki/javascript-es6-spread-operator-and-rest-parameters-b3e89d112281)

See the snippet below (though it is not typescript exactly).

```js
function baseFunction() {
  const params = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  const output = spreadFunction(...params);
}

function spreadFunction(...params) {
  // code here
  // console.log(params);
  const [attribute1, attribute2, attribute3] = params;
  console.log(attribute1);
  console.log(attribute2);
  console.log(attribute3);
}

// do action here
baseFunction();
```

Comment: Hi Rohit,  thanks for your answer. But if I will take the spreadFunction parameters with ...params as per as your example then that will not full fill the coding requirement because for this again I will need to use the params as array where as the  es6 spread operator does that automatically and converts those to function parameters.

Comment: @ArpanDas You can destruct the params though, I updated the answer. Spread operator converts those to function parameters at runtime, so typescript compiler complains about it.

Comment: Yes the updated idea is more helpful. Thanks! Though I wanted to use spread operator syntax without writing any extra line of code.