# How to make a local state that is compatible with an optional parameter and show error when adding wrong data to the state?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code where we simply want to add types A and B to make it compatible with the local state. The current issue is that adding the wrong key is not causing an error on the type.

```js
interface DataA {
a: boolean,
b: boolean,
c: boolean,
}

interface DataB { 
a: boolean,
b: boolean,
c: boolean,
d: boolean
}

const initialState: DataA | DataB = {
a: false,
b: false,
c: false
};

// Local state
const [weekData, setWeekData] = useState(initialState);


const data = (data ?? []).filter((el) => el.id === weekFocus)[0] as DataA | DataB;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
   setWeekData({
      a: data.a,
      b: data.b,
      c: data.c ,       
        // optional not showing error even that i want to add a key that is not compatible with state.
        ...(data.d && { wrongKey: data.d }),
      });
    }
  }, []);
```

Comment: I think this is not related to the optional, but it has something to do with the spread operator. Have a read on this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44525777/typescript-type-not-working-with-spread-operator
And here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47995